# Order String array with format in BashScript

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I got an array of strings with format: "XXXX YYYY ZZZZ WWWW"

i need to sort by YYYY; but if i use the common "sort", will be sorted by XXXXX not by YYYY.

I tried to put each element into a diccionary, using the YYYY as key; and using the key of diccionaries as array, then sort this array and take the elements. Anyone thinks another format, "more elegant"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely still use the `sort` command.

From the Linux manual page for `sort`:

> NAME
>          sort - sort lines of text files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          sort [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>          sort [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Write sorted concatenation of all FILE(s) to standard output.
>
> Mandatory  arguments  to  long  options are mandatory for short options
>          too.
>
> -k, --key=KEYDEF
>                 sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

And so you can do this:

`sort -k2`

And it will sort your input based on the 2nd key assuming the default delimeter is whitespace.

Comment: Reading the manual i skip this parameter. Sorry for silly question

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sort` command with `-k 2` in order to act on second field.